# PHP: strtotime() adds 3 days to date when it's not supposed to

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have the following string in my `strtotime()`:

`"2021W32Monday"`

I expected to get the date of the Monday in the 32nd week of the year 2021, which is the 9th of August 2021. Instead I got the 12th of August 2021.

I experimented a bit with other weekday, here's what I got for each:

`"2021W32Tuesday"`

- Result: 13th of August 2021
- Expected: 10th of August 2021

`"2021W32Wednesday"`

- Result: 14th of August 2021
- Expected: 11th of August 2021

`"2021W31Monday"`

- Result: 5th of August 2021
- Expected: 2nd of August 2021

Basically, the dates it gives me all seem 3 days too far. Why is this the case? I don't have any +3 anywhere, the whole command I'm currently using is literally `var_dump(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2021W31Monday")))`

The issue seems to be with the format of the string, though, since when I simply use "today" it gives me the correct date.

Comment: My guess - is that really a format that `strtotime()` should recognise?  The only one I see [in the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) that includes week is a [compound format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) which expects the day as a number.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. Separately, what I used all seems to work. "This Monday"/"Last Monday" will correctly give me the last/next monday and "2021W31" will correctly give me the first day of the 32nd week of 2021, the only issue seems to be once I add the weekday to the week of the year... But I will try adding the day as a number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it wrong as far as I know you should you it like this `2021W323` where first 4-digit `2021` stands for year. Following 3-digits `W32` stands for week number and than last digit `3` stands for 3rd day of the week.

You can also use it with dash seperator `2021-W32-3`

When I tried your examples day names with string I get -4 day date. I am not sure how this even work.

Here is an additional function for you hope it helps :)

```
function get_week_num($day_name) {
  $week_days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
  $week_num = array_keys($week_days, $day_name)[0];
  return $week_num + 1;
}

get_week_num("Wednesday");
```

Comment: thank you, this works like a charm! I'm a little surprised, though, since strtotime() usually accepts written weekdays (i.e. "this Monday")... but as long as it works, I'm happy :D!